# Setting specific day to print specific message in the django template

Tags: django, django-templates

Here is my model:

```
class Sitting(models.Model):
    sit_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    cut_off_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    ballot_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    sess_no = models.ForeignKey(Session,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre = TreeForeignKey('Genre', null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
```

here is my view:

```
def sitting_list(request):
    sitting=Sitting.objects.select_related('genre')

    return render(
        request,
        'genre/sitting_list.html',
        {'sittings':sitting, },  )
```

Here is my template:

```
{% block content %}
<table>
    <tr>
  <th>Sitting Day & Date</th>
  <th>Ministry/Division</th>
  <th>Ballot Date</th>

    </tr>
    {% for sitting in sittings %}
    <tr>
       <td> {{ sitting.sit_date|date:"l, d F, Y" }}</td>

    {% for genre in sitting.genre.get_descendants %}

             <td> {{ genre }},</td>

        {% endfor %}
        <td>(Ballot: {{ sitting.ballot_date}})</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

It gave following output:

[image]

Edit :

But I want following output:

[image]

You can see from my desired output, Ministry's name only come when no division exists. Moreover numbering and last full stop also not coming.

I hope this can also be fixed with your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add an if statement to see if the [`weekday`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) is 2 (0-6 mon-sun)

```
 <td> 
{% if sitting.sit_date.weekday == 2 %}
      extra stuff
 {% endif %}
 {% for genre in sitting.genre.get_descendants %}
      {{ genre }},
 {% endfor %}
</td>
```

Note: Also moved the td so you get the formatting style you wanted.

Comment: It iterated over every ministry/divisions and gave output many lines instead of one line, see the result: First 30 minutes for PMQ
Ministry A,

First 30 minutes for PMQ
Division A,

First 30 minutes for PMQ
Division B,

First 30 minutes for PMQ
Division C,

First 30 minutes for PMQ ...

Comment: I also get same result by modifying your first post as:
{% with dow=sitting.sit_date.weekday %}
                {% if dow == 2 %}
                  <p>First 30 minutes for PMQ</p>
                  {% endif %}
             {% for genre in sitting.genre.get_descendants %}

                  {{ genre }},
             {% endfor %}
            {% endwith %}

Comment: Still numbering and last full stop not showing. One more thing I need to show my ministry/division name when ministry don't have division then only ministry's name shown but when ministry has divisions then only divisions name are shown not ministry name. I updated my desired output in the Edit portion I hope you understand my desired output.