# How to show only first level child when second level child doen't exists otherwise show second level child in django MPTT

Tags: django, django-mptt

I got following output from django-mptt tree:

```
Group-2    
    Ministry E
        Division G
        Division Z
    Ministry F
        Division I
        Division J

Group-3    
    Ministry P
        Division X
        Division Y
    Ministry Q
    Ministry R
        Division U
        Division V
```

But I want to show it as follows:

```
        Division G
        Division Z

        Division I
        Division J 

        Division X
        Division Y

    Ministry Q

        Division U
        Division V
```

That means level 1 only shows when level 2 not exists otherwise level 2 only shows. 
I tried using Model.objects.filter(level=1) but it gives only one level not both selectively. I also tried Model.objects.filter(level__gt=0) it gives both level not obey the condition.

How can I get both level maintaining conditions?

EDIT:

```
{% block content %}


{% load mptt_tags %}
{% for instance in Genre.objects.all %}
    {% if instance.is_leaf_node %}
        {{ instance }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Views:

```
def show_genres(request):
    instances = Genre.objects.filter(children__isnull=True)
    return render(request,
                  'genre/template.html', {'instances': instances})
```

URLS:

```
url(r'^genres/$', show_genres, name="genre_list",)
```

Model:

```
 class Genre(MPTTModel):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

class MPTTMeta:

    order_insertion_by=['name']
```

Comment: Add models.py listing

Comment: You will get my model.py here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822165/setting-specific-day-to-print-specific-message-in-the-django-template/38822240?noredirect=1#comment65012865_38822240

Comment: I also added my Genre model in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show only the leaf nodes

**Solution #1 - in template:**

```
{% for instance in Model.objects.all %}
    {% if instance.is_leaf_node %}
        {{ instance }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Solution #2 - in view:**

```
instances = Model.objects.filter(children__isnull=True)
return render(request, 'template.html', {'instances': instances})
```

Comment: It shows nothing. I am posting my view, template and url in EDIT. I already posted my view, template and url

Comment: Try to add `__unicode__` (or `__str__` if Python3) method to `Genre`. Or use in template `{{ instance.name }}`.

Comment: I solved this with your first solution made little changes.